# Objective-c property and memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, memory, exc-bad-access

Just a quick question:
I've got an array, name it sourceArray. This array has dictionaries in it. 
I've got a retained property, which is used to hold one item from the array. 
When I set the property from the array it works fine. 
But, when I set it with an other item, and back to the first, I got a bad_access exception, since the first item has been released.

My question is why? In the source array, items are retained, and when I set the property it retains to. When I set it again, the setter release the old value, and retain the new. I guess... But apparently it doesn't work in this way.

Example:

```
 [self setProperty:[sourceArray objectAtIndex:0]];
 [self setProperty:[sourceArray objectAtIndex:1]];
 [self setProperty:[sourceArray objectAtIndex:0]]; ---> Exception
```

Comment: Have you written your own `setProperty` method? What does it look like?

Comment: are these lines of code in consecutive lines?

Comment: Nope, I hadn't written my own set method.

Comment: And these lines are not consecutive lines. Actually my method got a number, which tell to it which object should be set.

Comment: try putting these in consecutive lines..and check if it success..

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. 
In other place, I've a line:

```
property = [sourceArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

It looks like when I use the set method, the old value get released, no matter that it hasn't been retained (since in the first time, I didn't use the set method). 
My fault...